# Conditional expectation of a component in a multinomial distribution: understanding of complex calculations

Tags: probability-distributions, summation, factorial, fractions, multinomial-distribution

This is in the context of the expected value of a multinomial distribution in statistics, but I don't think that needs to be known for this specific question.

I'm confused about how an answer in my textbook simplifies the first equality into the second equality. It seems a bit out of the blue, and after some looking at, I don't know how the last equality was created.

**Edit:** n is a fixed positive integer.

[image]

If someone could help me out, that'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Cancel the common $(1-p_2-\dots-p_{k-1})^{n-x_2-\dots-x_{k-1}}$, $x_1$ with that from $x_1!$ and you have...

Comment: @user10354138 I have provided an answer to this question to which I was understanding nothing at all at first (and even second) sight. Besides, as I see it on your profile, you are in the domain of calibration geometry, there is an attracting question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4145658);  but I have some difficulty to understand the real issue...

Answer (score 1):

With compact notations

$$
\begin{cases}a&=&1-p_2-p_3-...-p_{k-1}\\b&=&n-x_2-...-x_{k-1}\end{cases},$$

your sum becomes

$$\sum_{x_1=0}^b x_1\binom{b}{x_1}\frac{a^{-x_1+b}p_1^{x_1}}{a^b}$$

$$=\sum_{x_1=0}^b x_1\binom{b}{x_1} \left(\frac{p_1}{a}\right)^{x_1}$$

where we recognize the mathematical expectation of a binomial law $Bin(b,\frac{p_1}{a})$ which is indeed

$$b \frac{p_1}{a} \tag{1}$$

as desired.

Remarks:

1. The fact that this conditional expectation (1) is proportional to the ratio of probability $p_1$ to the complementary probability $a=1-p_2-p_3- ... -p_{k-1}$ is quite normal...
2. A [similar issue](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/536631).

Comment: At last, I have succeded ! This, after correcting a certain number of errors (I had in particular misinterpreted the two first lines as being separate lines instead of a product).

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order to attract further readers. I think it's important to give the context of multinomial distribution, a reason for this being that one can think in this way (as I have done) to invoke probability results.